# Versioned cloud-based social code snippet management

Tags: version-control, tags, cloud, collaboration, code-snippets

It seems a lot to ask, but I'm looking for a cloud-based solution to managing code snippets.  I am looking for:

- Tags
- User accounts (I want to be able to see all of my snippets on a single page)
- syntax highlighting
- versioning - myself or others should be able to edit my snippets to improve them and have revisions save so that I can go back and use an older version if I prefer.
- straightforward UI with minimal advertising if any

Does anyone know of a solution which meets these requirements?  If not, would anyone be interested in something like this?  As a software engineer, after step zero (does it already exist), I'm perfectly willing to go onto step 1 (would other people use it? If so, make it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.codebarrel.com

it has everything you asked for

Comment: I'm gonna take a look at this. It looks like it should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Gist.

http://gist.github.com/

Except for the tags part. But it might be workable anyway.

Comment: I saw this, but I'm not sure how much I'd like it.  Also,the integration into an existing version control system is nice, but I don't use git.  When I said version controlled I meant more that it saves revisions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a site for this.  The *very* rough (as in: barely works, but not even functional yet) initial version is here: https://github.com/jasongrout/snippets